# Ember one way binding for text field

Tags: ember.js

How do I create a view that can write to a model, but does not read from it. Basically one way binding.

I have a rough attempt, but it isn't a great solution and does not work.

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.NewTextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
    focusIn: function() {
        this.valueBinding = "comment";
    },
    focusOut: function() {
        this.valueBinding = null;
    }
});
```

See the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/tylermercier/dcNLt/1/

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a solution by binding to the value of the textfield and watching for it to change, I can update the model in the controller.

```
App.NewTextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
    valueDidChange: function() {
        value = this.get('value');
        controller = this.get('targetObject');
        controller.set('comment', value)
    }.observes('value')
});
```

The working solution is here. Not that the valueBinding was removed.
http://jsfiddle.net/tylermercier/dcNLt/2/

This isn't perfect though. I will have trouble clearing the textfields on update.